# mv: cannot move ‘/etc/default/keyboard.tmp’ to ‘/etc/default/keyboard’: Operation not permitted

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo

I run:

```
sudo mv /etc/default/keyboard.tmp /etc/default/keyboard
```

I get this error:

```
mv: cannot move ‘/etc/default/keyboard.tmp’ to ‘/etc/default/keyboard’: Operation not permitted
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Hmh

a simple cp should do it, or am I wrong?

```
cp /etc/default/keyboard.tmp /etc/default/keyboard
```

then try to do a forced removal

```
rm -rf /etc/default/keyboard.tmp
```

If it still doesn't work I suggest, that the file is in use by a service or daemon or application and will be deleted after reboot or at least the Service/daemon/application has been closed.

Comment: No :) but thank you for trying